# How to save and share bookmarks on the web?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, browser, bookmarks

I'm finding myself more and more both afraid for the safety of my bookmarks and in need of sharing my bookmarks across many computers, I'm looking for a web solution to save and share (some publicly) my bookmarks.

What do you use for bookmark sharing?

btw. using chrome, would love easy integration.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [delicious.com](http://delicious.com) or [pinboard.in](http://pinboard.in)?

Answer (score 1):

Xmarks.com sounds closest to what you're describing. There were rumors of it shutting down last year, but it was acquired by LastPass and seems to be chugging along.

[Yet Another Extension for Google Bookmarks Extension](http://%28https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jdnejaepfmacfdmhkplckpfdcjgbeode%29) lives as an icon on your Chrome browser for one-click saves, and shows bookmarks in a tree view. Google also has a bookmarklet for it if you don't like extensions. Bookmarks are saved to Google, not just Chrome, so you can access them in any browser at google.com/bookmarks. It has one-click sharing to G+ (I know ...), but you can also [save to a list](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/03/collaborative-bookmarking-with-lists.html) and share that anywhere.

Read it Later (readitlaterlist.com), Instapaper.com and Readability.com are marketed for offline reading, but I also use them for saving and sharing bookmarks. They all have apps, bookmarklets and Web interfaces for easy saving and sharing.

I'm still a new user so can only submit 2 hyperlinks. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Chrome have a built in synchronization system. It uses your Google profile for doing it. Just press the wrench button and select "Enter with your google account" entry.

Comment: I need to be able to access it w/o installing chrome. I need it at work or maybe on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Diigo](http://www.diigo.com)?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.